# groupoid of finite sets.

Tags: groupoids

I'm newbie to the category and groupoid, and I got confused about the definition of groupoids.

In the definition of groupoid in the Wikipedia, it says a groupoid is a "small" category such that every morphism is isomorphism.

And I'm sure I'm wrong, but I don't know why the finite sets with bijections form a groupoid (this may not be true, and if i'm not correct, please correct me), since the class of finite sets is not a set, which is a requirement to be a small category.

...

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1114/whats-a-groupoid-whats-a-good-example-of-a-groupoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to restrict attention to small groupoids. A groupoid should just be a category such that every morphism is an isomorphism. In any case, the groupoid of finite sets and bijections is *essentially* small, meaning that it's equivalent to a small groupoid, and that's usually good enough.